# Tableless layout table generator

Tags: web-development, html

I am looking for a table generator based on div tag that can generate html code.

Comment: Please consider adding a lot more information to this question. Currently, it is so ambiguous that it can not be answered and will likely be closed in the very near future.

Comment: @Tim Post but at least two men could try to do it.

Comment: @igor - Which is why I did not vote to close it immediately, on the chance that you might get a good answer (and it appears that you have). :)

Comment: Despite the good answers, this is still a REALLY poor question a) because of the lack of information and confusing wording b) because - depending on what the question actually is - it's unlikely to be of use to anyone else. Can someone with edit permissions tidy it up ASAP, please?

Comment: @Bobby Jack i know and so is: there are no bad questions, there are bad answers. i think moderator should stop this negative person (aka Bobby Jack). So please, be more polite. i got information what i want from the professionals and i have no time for apologies to persons like you. :)

Comment: @igor please understand, I'm not saying your question is without value, just that it needs to be rewritten to be meaningful to a wider audience. One aim of the SE family of sites is to provide long-term, high quality content that can be reused and referenced (think wikipedia). This is an example of a question that would really benefit from an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to generate a table using only divs you are most likely either:

**a) Trying to generate a layout without using tables**

Probably needing to convert an existing table based layout to match the current attitude that "tables are bad".

In which case there is no generator to convert your existing table based layout. You'll need to do the hard work of converting things.

**b) Trying to present tabular data using only divs**

Despite the general wisdom of "tables are bad" it is important to realize that they **do** still serve a purpose. That purpose is to present **tabular** data, i.e. data that is most naturally displayed in table form. For that kind of data you should continue to use the table tag!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is really possible or wise. Converting a table, which was not intended for layout anyway, into a set of `<div>` tags will result in the same messy, unmaintainable code.

You should learn HTML and CSS and then do it yourself manually. A grid system like [960.gs](http://960.gs/) can help you keep things neat with columns and such.

Comment: +1 thank you for reference (960). it seems as the one of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://celoxsystems.com/div_tbl_frm.html

Comment: If you're going to self promote yourself be honest and up front about it.